Cold Turkey alternative for Linux (self control/time wasting/productivity software)
Cold Turkey allows you to:

block websites
block programs
do both of those on a schedule
is hardened against attempts to evade/uninstall it while it is in blocking mode

Sadly it only works on MacOS and Windows.
I want Linux alternatives (currently running Pop OS) that have at least one but preferably more of these functions.
I am aware of Chomper, a Linux tool that blocks websites, but not applications. Its install script doesn't work anymore, and the developer is no longer active on reddit and github although it may be possible to reach them via their website.
I am NOT interested in browser plugins on their own (e.g. LeechBlock/StayFocusd) since they are too easy to evade.
Timekpr-nExT appears to focus more on limiting screentime for kids.

For a solid Linux alternative that meets your needs, check out DigitalZen. It's a comprehensive tool that:
Blocks websites and desktop applications on a set schedule.
Works system-wide, not just as a browser extension, so it’s much harder to bypass.
Has features designed to help you stay focused and productive.
It's built to be reliable, offering peace of mind that once it's in blocking mode, it's not easy to bypass or uninstall until the timer runs out. Perfect for Pop!_OS and other Linux distros.
And full transparency: I'm part of the dev team behind it :-)

Thank you Wazime! That is pretty dope. And lifetime free for early adopters sounds like a really good deal!
